# Conda thinks package specifications are incompatible, even though they are not

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

Running the command:

```
 conda create -y --name test -c bioconda glimmer=3.02 blast=2.9.0 trnascan-se=2.0.6 hhsuite
```

Produced the following error output:

```
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                 

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package perl conflicts for:
blast=2.9.0 -> perl[version='>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0']
hhsuite -> perl[version='>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0']
trnascan-se=2.0.6 -> perl[version='>=5.26.2,<5.26.3.0a0']
blast=2.9.0 -> entrez-direct -> perl[version='5.22.0.*|>=5.26.0,<5.27.0a0|>=5.26.2,<5.27.0a0']

Package libcxx conflicts for:
blast=2.9.0 -> pcre[version='>=8.44,<9.0a0'] -> libcxx[version='>=10.0.0']
blast=2.9.0 -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1|>=9.0.1']

Package libcxxabi conflicts for:
blast=2.9.0 -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1'] -> libcxxabi==4.0.1[build='hebd6815_0|hcfea43d_1']
hhsuite -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1'] -> libcxxabi==4.0.1[build='hebd6815_0|hcfea43d_1']
```

From the output, none of the packages' dependencies seem to be in conflict with each other. How do I create this environment?

Comment: The error message is really unhelpful (not your fault). One way to troubleshoot is to remove a package or two from the command and see if it solves; that can at least help you narrow down which is the problem. I'm going to assume you need precisely the pinned versions of `glimmer`, `blast`, and `trnascan-se`, otherwise those pins are likely to be a cause of issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bioconda Channel Specification

The inability to solve *could* be caused by having a nonstandard channel specification.<sup>**1**</sup> [The official recommendation for Bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/user/install.html#set-up-channels) is to use:

```yaml
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

with [strict priority](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html#strict-channel-priority). I can solve without issue using the following YAML<sup>**2**</sup>

**foo.yaml**

```yaml
name: foo
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - glimmer=3.02 
  - blast=2.9.0 
  - trnascan-se=2.0.6 
  - hhsuite
```

then

```bash
conda env create -n foo -f foo.yaml
```

However, if I don't include the **conda-forge** channel, I get a similar error as with OP.

Not conclusive, but worth a try.

---

<sub>[1] As for the package conflict report output not being helpful: unfortunately, this has been a problem for a while now.</sub>

<sub>[2] Consider using YAMLs instead of shell one-liners, especially in a scientific context. It yields a manifest artifact of how an environment was specified, and this can then be version controlled.</sub>